# How to prevent Hibernate from creating duplicates in many to one mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two simple objects; Person and City.  A City may have multiple Persons but a Person only one City.  I would like to be able to save a Person and have Hibernate automatically save the City - only if it is a new City - that is cities should be unique.  With my mapping I find that every time a Person is saved, a new City is inserted in the database, regardless if it is already there.  I am sure that this is fairly straight forward, however I am new to Hibernate and struggling with it.  Note, if I save two Person with a single City in one session - all works.  This is an issue across sessions.  I have also created equals and hashcode methods in the City class as per below.

```
Person.hbm.xml

  <id name="id" type="long" column="id" >
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <property name="firstName">
   <column name="firstname" />
  </property>

 <many-to-one name="city" class="com.project.City" cascade="save-update">
  <column name="cityId" not-null="true" />
 </many-to-one>


City.hbm.xml

   <id name="id" type="long" column="id" >
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <property name="description" unique="true">
   <column name="description" />
  </property>


public class City implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String description;

      // getters and setters

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this==other) return true;
        if ( !(other instanceof City) ) return false;
        final City that = (City) other;
        return this.description.equals( that.getDescription() );
    }   

    public int hashCode() {
        return description.hashCode();
    }    
}




    try {
      Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

      Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(City.class);
      criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("description", city.getDescription()));
      criteria.setMaxResults(1);

      // Possible to use:
      // List<City> cities = criteria.list();
      // However, this generates warnings about unsafe casting.  If you use this then
      // set @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      List<City> cities = HibernateUtil.castList(City.class, criteria.list());

      if (cities.isEmpty())  {
          session.save(city);
        }
      else  {
          city = (City) cities.get(0);
        }
          session.flush();
          tx.commit();
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
          return null;
            }
      }
return city;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if ( !(other instanceof Ward) ) return false;
    final Ward that = (Ward) other;
```

Shouldn't this be City instead of Ward?

Comment: How are you setting the City property in your other objects? How are you creating the City objects?

Comment: I create a city object and set the description say: city.setDescription("Paris") and then person.setCity(city).  If the city with description="Paris" is used in two separate Person "save" sessions, it is saved twice (unless unique is set for the description column - then I get an exception on the second save).  I was hoping that I could construct a relationship that would build the City table with unique entries through the saving of Person objects.

Comment: You need to look up the city object in your database to get the ID - this is how it will make it unique.  Another option is to make the ID field the string.

Comment: thank you for your comments - so it should be a two step process; test for city "Paris", if there, retrieve then person.setCity(city) where city is the retrieved object then save person.  Otherwise save person with new city.  I guess this would all have to be within a single transaction.  I had thought of using the description as the ID field - hence the equals and hashcode in the City class, but I am not sure how to force Hibernate to use it as the key?

Comment: I think you just need <id name="description" type="string".. etc.  Here's an example http://oatv.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/01/14/hibernate.html?page=2.  You won't need a generator for this one.

Comment: Ok - I understand this now.  I think the best approach is to test for a City of description Paris - if it is not there - save it - if it is - retrieve it and set it as the city for the Person object.  The person object can then be saved without duplicating the city.  Thank you for your guidance

Comment: Just my two cents: This is probably a great question for someone learning Hibernate. Could you guys put this entire discussion as an answer?